# How to achieve this table layout with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

**EDIT 2: I'm talking about the layout of the table, not the colours.**

I need to style my table so that it appears as such:

[image]

The idea is to have the first th td pair on top and the rest should be in line under it.

Is that feasible through CSS?

I don't have control over the HTML here so CSS is my only option.

Edit:
Here's the HTML

```
<div class="content">
      <table>
         <thead>
      <tr>
                  <th class="thtitle" >
            Title         </th>
                  <th class="thvalue" >
            Value         </th>
                  <th class="thquantity" >
            Quantity          </th>
                  <th class="thsum" >
            Sum          </th>
              </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <tr class="first">
              <td class="tdtitle" >…</td>
<td class="tdvalue" >…</td>
<td class="tdquantity" >…</td>
<td class="tdsum" >…</td>

</tr>
          <tr class="last">
              <td class="tdtitle" >…</td>
<td class="tdvalue" >…</td>
<td class="tdquantity" >…</td>
<td class="tdsum" >…</td>
              </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Show how current html table looks like

Comment: `th` in third row? it is supposed to be `table header`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: @Justinas I provided the HTML of the table

Comment: @Gagan You're right I should have provided more info and the things i've tried. I tried to have the first th td pair to be display: block and take the whole width and the rest to be display: inline. I played with floats but everything I tried came short.

Comment: not exactly as per the image. but here is a workaround. to achieve this would required a lots of `position:absolute`. http://jsbin.com/yokenote/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Edit 2:

I've added a fiddle that does exactly what you want, but be warned that nth-child doesnt play nice in IE8. It also assumes that the HTML you gave us is ALWAYS that way [ie always has the same amount of th/td's].

http://jsfiddle.net/8awAj/

Edit:

Is the html you posted ALWAYS like that? Ie never any more or less headings etc?

This isn't 100% what you want, but its kind of close. To get exactly what you want you would have to do a LOT of manual absolute positioning using :nth-child which would be horrible.

http://jsfiddle.net/9JWpA/

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

th {
    background: yellow;
}

td {
    background: green;
}

th,
td {
    top: 40px;
    width: 16.666%;
    position: absolute;
}

th:first-child,
td:first-child {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
td:first-child {
    top: 20px;
}

th:nth-child(2) {
    left: 0;  
}
td:nth-child(2) {
    left: 16.666%;    
}
th:nth-child(3) {
    left: 33.333%;  
}
td:nth-child(3) {
    left: 49.998%;    
}
th:nth-child(4) {
    left: 66.666%;  
}
td:nth-child(4) {
    left: 83.33%;    
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean the color but the layout of the cells

Comment: Thanks giving this a try.

Comment: Added a fiddle that does exactly what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

try this..

http://jsfiddle.net/9JWpA/

**html:**

```
<table cellspacing=0;>
    <tr><th colspan="6">th</th></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="6">td</td></tr>
    <tr><th>th</th><td>td</td><th>th</th><td>td</td><th>th</th><td>td</td></tr>
</table>
```

**css:**

```
table
{
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:left;
}

th
{
    background:yellow;
}
td
{
    background:green;
}
```